# How to do this in haskell? 

Tags: haskell, erlang

How can I do this in haskell?

```
equal(S,S) -> true;
equal(S1, S2) -> {differ, S1, S2}.
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain a bit what this is supposed to do for people that do not know erlang...? You want a function that compare two things ? You can use `compare`, or just the good ol' `==` operator.

Comment: Like Prolog by any chance? Look at the Curry programming language.

Answer (score 12):

Haskell has a perfectly serviceable `(==)` operator for checking equality (on types for which equality is defined) so I'm assuming you're referring to something else here besides merely testing equality.

I don't know Erlang, but given that you wrote `equal(S, S)` my first guess would be that you want pattern matches to express equality by reusing the variable name. Unfortunately Haskell (and ML-style in general) pattern matching is less powerful than in languages like Prolog; all the pattern can do is bind variables, not perform full unification.

It's true that there are constant value patterns like `foo [1,2] = ...` but that's just syntactic sugar for a binding and equality check, and it's only done for constant values, not variables.

The usual Haskell approach would probably be **pattern guards**, like this:

```
data EqualResult a b = Yep | Nope (a, b) deriving (Show, Eq)

equal :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> EqualResult a a
equal s1 s2 | s1 == s2  = Yep
            | otherwise = Nope (s1, s2)
```

On the off chance that you wanted some sort of reference equality instead of checking for equal values, that doesn't work because it doesn't even make sense in Haskell.

**Edit:** It has been pointed out to me that you may also have been asking about returning different result types. Working with types should be covered well in any introduction to Haskell, but the short version in this case is that if you need to return one of two possible types, you need a data type with one constructor for each; you then examine the result using pattern matching (in a declaration or `case` expression).

In this case, to make it look more like your function I've made a special-purpose type with two constructors: One indicating equality (with no further details) and one indicating inequality that holds a pair of values. You can also do it in a generic way using the built-in type `Either a b`, which has two constructors `Left a` and `Right b`.

Comment: My guess is that it's the `true`/`{differ, S1, S2}` thing that Gmp was looking for, so you might want to explain why you're using an `EqualResult` to replace that.  (In other words, static typing.)

Comment: @Antal S-Z: Oh, good point, thanks. I've edited it to add some stuff about that.

Comment: I have a list of lists on which I used the map function and sort, as I'm Lazy do not know how to assess whether the function is executing, so I thought of using boolean values to compare an element with the other as to whether the final list is sorted .

Comment: let !pmapasort =  (pmapa  psort   conteudo) `using` (parList rdeepseq)

Comment: @Gmp: Why would you do that? If you sorted it, you sorted it. If you use the result, you'll get it. If not, who cares? Don't think of Haskell functions as being "executed". They're just functions.

Comment: Actually I know the time it takes to do the ordering, I will not print, nor will I use the function elsewhere. How can I ensure that my function is being performed correctly?

I have this program in Erlang, the Book of Joe, now I'm doing in Haskell.

Comment: @Gmp: If you want to benchmark a function, use something like [Criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion). In actual code, it doesn't make sense to worry about it.